# how to delay requests in node js

Tags: node.js, express

this is my code i'm trying to create an email scheduler

```
router.post(`/blogs`, async (req, res) => {
  let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_PW
    }
  });
  const data = {
    to: `${req.body.to}`,
    second: `${req.body.second}`,
    minute: `${req.body.minute}`,
  };
  const task = cronJob.schedule(`*/${data.minute}`, () => {
    mailTransporter.sendMail(data, err => {
    });
  })
    task.stop();

});
```

each time i set the time to more than 30 seconds i get

```
"Process timed out after 30 seconds"
```

from the log on my deployed server,which means my response is been delayed to get to the backend
so i'm asking is there a way i can set a up loader to keep the server spinning before my request is been made, so as the avoid getting a 30 seconds error

Comment: does ur server sleep?

Comment: I think you need to send a `Response` back to the requester so after scheduling sending something like `res.status(200).send({ success: true });` or something. Does that work?

Comment: Also I would move the creation of the transporter outside of this endpoint, right now it is establishing a new connection everytime this endpoint is called which is not necessary only the `mailTranporter.sendMail` part should be inside the callback

Comment: Also task is defined in the scope of the callback and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of things that I'd suggest changing, especially storing your data somewhere other than the current running process, but I'll keep things as close as possible to your question.

You're timing out because you're *never* responding. Nothing to do with the cron library you're using.

You can up the timeout in express for sure, but that's a really bad idea unless you know what you're doing and what effect it will have on other processes. Besides, why would you setup a cron and wait for it to finish, that makes no sense.

```js
// you only need one instance of this mailer, create it outside your handler
let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_PW
  }
});

router.post(`/blogs`, async (req, res) => {

  // why the string literals?
  const data = {
    to: req.body.to,
    second: req.body.second,
    minute: req.body.minute,
  };

  // I would store these cronjobs in some sort of DB and have a separate
  // process manage them, otherwise they will be lost on restart
  const task = cronJob.schedule(`*/${data.minute}`, () => {
    mailTransporter.sendMail(data, err => { 
      console.log(err)
    });
  })

  // if you're using node-cron this will stop your task
  // before it has even run, so I'm commenting this out
  // task.stop(); 
  
  res.send(); // respond to the client

});
```